# Android: set sdk.dir in local.properties to ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, android-studio, environment-variables

So the `local.properties` file holds the reference to the Android SDK directory in `sdk.dir` variable. For me it is `sdk.dir=/Users/rajkiran/Library/Android/sdk`. On my CI machine, the `sdk.dir` refers to the SDK directory which points to an invalid location since the username is different.

Is there any way so that I can set SDK directory as my `ANDROID_HOME`?

Perhaps something like this: `sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME`, so that on my CI machine, it will set the SDK directory from the environment variable?

Comment: whenever you import project in android studio. it tells you that sdk path from another computer is not available and automatically uses sdk path available in your computer. No need to change it manually

Comment: @VivekMishra Right. But for that, I need to have Android Studio installed on that computer which is not required just for building the apk on my CI machine. Updated the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*local.properties* should **not** be part of the versioned code. It's used as your local project configuration and Android Studio will create it based on on `ANDROID_HOME` if it doesn't exist yet.

If *local.properties* is not available, Gradle will use `ANDROID_HOME` automatically.

If *local.properties* is available, Gradle will use this file having a wrong `sdk.dir` set and fail.

Comment: Yes, so if you import your project from somewhere else, make sure to **remove** the `local.properties` file, or you will likely have the wrong path in there. *Android-Studio* do not automatically update this file, as the text in it give the impression, if it already exists.

Comment: Me too @Rajkiran !

Comment: “local.properties should not be part of the versioned code.” Yes! Thank you!

Comment: “make sure to remove the local.properties file” Thank you !