# SDK Location not Found In Gradle Command Line Linux

Tags: android, linux, gradle, fdroid

I am trying to build my project using `fdroid` but it keeps failing when it gets to `gradle`. The project builds well in android studio but it always fail in gradle command line. I have search google multiple times but i could not get help from any website. I have set my `ANDROID_HOME` to `/home/collins/Android/Sdk` but it seems gradle ignores the variable, Each time i try to build, i noticed that gradle generates a `local.properties` file with the wrong sdk location value:

```
sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME
sdk-location=$ANDROID_HOME
```

I don't know if there is a way to set the global default value for any project in gradle. Here is the full log from `fdroid build`

```
INFO: Building version 3.0 (3) of com.simpledecredwidget
INFO: Getting source for revision 0ca18981c4b3825861b07e1f2444f711fc8a4fa5
INFO: Creating local.properties file at build/com.simpledecredwidget/local.properties
INFO: Creating local.properties file at build/com.simpledecredwidget/app/local.properties
INFO: Cleaning Gradle project...
ERROR: Could not build app com.simpledecredwidget: Error cleaning com.simpledecredwidget:3.0
==== detail begin ====
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /home/collins/Documents/Projects/fdroiddata/build/com.simpledecredwidget/app/$ANDROID_NDK.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/home/collins/Documents/Projects/fdroiddata/build/com.simpledecredwidget/$ANDROID_HOME' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
==== detail end ====
INFO: Build for app com.simpledecredwidget failed:
Error cleaning com.simpledecredwidget:3.0
==== detail begin ====
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /home/collins/Documents/Projects/fdroiddata/build/com.simpledecredwidget/app/$ANDROID_NDK.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/home/collins/Documents/Projects/fdroiddata/build/com.simpledecredwidget/$ANDROID_HOME' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
==== detail end ====
INFO: Finished.
INFO: 1 builds failed
```

**EDIT**
As you can see in the error above, The sdk location `/home/collins/Documents/Projects/fdroiddata/build/com.simpledecredwidget/$ANDROID_HOME` was used which was incorrect, i don't know where this bug is coming because a different value was set in local.properties file which value is `sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: set sdk.dir in local.properties to ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097528/android-set-sdk-dir-in-local-properties-to-android-home-environment-variable)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, read the question properly, my gradle sets it to the $ANDROID_HOME, then uses a wrong value `/home/collins/Documents/Projects/fdroiddata/build/com.simpledecredwidget/$ANDROID_HOME` that is the current issue, and not setting the local.properties value